# Memory-efficient ResourceManager for SDL textures

Tags: c++, c++11, sdl

I'm working with a few SDL2 examples in C++11 and i'm looking into building a `ResourceManager` for my game. This class would be responsible for managing all resources (loading, unloading, rendering, etc). In my mind, it works like this:

```
ResourceManager manager = ResourceManager();
manager.addSprite("player", "sprites/player.png");
manager.addAudio("background", "music/song.mp3");

Sprite player = manager.get("player");
player.render(0, 0);

Audio background = manager.get("background");
background.play();
```

I'm planning to store the resources in an array inside the ResourceManager class. Is this a good practice? Is there a better way of working with SDL resources?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a variety of different ways to do this. You should consider using some sort of hash table that relates your keys (string names) to your objects. Instead of a manager, the idea is more of a locator, because a manager implies that it controls the lifetime of the objects. Investigate how XNA's [ContentManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.content.contentmanager.aspx) works for an example of a really nice API for resource management. This is C#, obviously, but the API is really clean and friendly.

So my suggestion is, for basic resource location, you should use a [unordered map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map). You can wrap it if you'd like to add more functionality, such as lifetime management or content loading.

Based on your example, you could wrap the hash set and add your own templated Load method that works something like:

```
template <typename Type>
Type* ResourceManager::Load( char* name, char* filePath )
{
    Type* t = new Type( );
    t->Initialize( name, filePath ); // this implies that anything
                                     // to be added to your manager
                                     // will be required to have an Initialize
                                     // method with this signature.
    _resources[ name ] = t; // _resources is your hash_map<char*, void*>;

    return t;
}
```

This is obviously a crude example of resource management, but there is much more to learn about this topic in general. I suggest reading up on data structures (such as [linked lists](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list)and [binary trees](http://math.hws.edu/eck/cs225/s03/binary_trees/)) in general, and then look into design patterns like [factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern), [singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern), and [builder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern). These are just starting points, but are good enough to point you in the right direction for this kind of stuff. Good luck!

Comment: As I said, it does really depend on what you're doing. For resource location, I always run to maps/dictionaries because they have an excellent transparent API: I provide a key, that key is used to look up my data quickly.

Answer (score 0):

On the implementation details, no, avoid arrays. The STL has proper containers that are as efficient and much safer to use. In particular, `map`s and `unordered_map`s will do exactly the mapping between the name and the resource.

Concerning general design, I strongly recommend you look into what existing frameworks do. [OGRE 3D](http://www.ogre3d.org/) has a nice implementation of resource management classes tailored for games. In particular, it includes the ability to pre-load resources so you don't get slow-downs for loading resources on demand. You can also specify a "memory budget", so resources can be automatically unloaded.

Comment: Can a map have variable types? Like std::map<std::string, Sprite OR Audio> resources;

Comment: If `Sprite` and `Audio` share the same base class (say, `Resource`), yes, store a pointer to the base type, and downcast when you need it. In general each resource type will consume different (actual) resources, so it might be a better idea to have a `TextureManager`, `AudioManager`, etc, each working independently, even though they might share a common `ResourceManager` class as a base.